# How to import RSA keys on Mac OS X Yosemite?

Tags: terminal, osx-yosemite, keychain, ssh-keys

Doing the following:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
...
security import ~/.ssh/id_rsa -k login.keychain -t priv -f openssh2
```

I get the following error:

```
security: SecKeychainItemImport: Unknown format in import.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may convert it to X.509 pem first:

```
openssl rsa -in ~/.ssh/id_rsa -outform PEM -out id_rsa.pem
```

Then `security` will be able to recognize it:

```
security import id_rsa.pem
```

Sample output:

```
1 key imported.
```

Comment: `security import ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -t pub -f openssh2` works, so maybe the above doesn't work because of the private key passphrase...

Comment: @AndrejsIgumenovs You'll enter your passphrase when you convert the private key to pem. Then it can be successfully imported without the passphrase.